# How to remove showing of a contract source code from from etherscan?

Tags: etherscan

if somebody will tell me how to remove showing of a contract source code from appearing on etherscan? Once a contract is deployed? Is it possible or another contract should be deployed? thanks

Comment: What source? The bytecode?

Comment: Just the the tab on etherscan which says "contract source - Yes."

Comment: The contract source is here only if the creator uploaded it. Your OP sentence is confusing, what do you want to do ?

Comment: Yes. I created a contract and uploaded the source code and now I would like to remove it without creating a brand new contract.

Comment: Then you can't remove the code flr actual contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. Once the contract is verified, it is verified. Furthermore redeploying the contract won't do any good. If the contract has matching bytecode with a verified one, it will be possible to see the source code.

Your best bet is to modify the contract slightly, and redeploy it.

Answer (score -1):

recompile with different optimisation parameter, like optimisation - enabled, and different number of runs than it was by default (200), set it  5000 for instance, and redeploy. It will be different already from point of view of etherscan, no need to change source code.

Comment: This does not answer the question.